# Qt refresh abstract item model after adding data to database

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

how to reload the qabstract item model after I added data to database. so what I want is when I managed to add data to the database, QAbstractItemModel is refreshing or reload with the new data. But in this case, I success add data to database and the tree view not update, so to update this data I must close and open the widget again. Please help me what should I write on line *(// refresh proxymodel after add data to database)* on file teachersmodel.cpp?
**teachersmodel.cpp**:

```
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QDebug>
#include <iostream>
#include "mainwindow/teacherspage/teachersmodel.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace mongo;

TeachersModel::TeachersModel()
{
    int countRow = 0;
}

QDate TeachersModel::DateOfBirth(const BSONElement &datebirth)
{
    return QDate(QDateTime::fromTime_t(datebirth.date()/1000).date());
}

void TeachersModel::AddTeacher(QAbstractItemModel* model,
                               const QString &induk_no,
                               const QString &name,
                               const QString &phone,
                               const QDate &datebirth,
                               const QString &sex,
                               const QString &certificate,
                               const QString &position,
                               const QString &teach,
                               const QString &fieldofstudy,
                               const QString &id)
{
    model->insertRow(0);
    model->setData(model->index(0, 0), induk_no);
    model->setData(model->index(0, 1), name);
    model->setData(model->index(0, 2), phone);
    model->setData(model->index(0, 3), datebirth);
    model->setData(model->index(0, 4), sex);
    model->setData(model->index(0, 5), certificate);
    model->setData(model->index(0, 6), position);
    model->setData(model->index(0, 7), teach);
    model->setData(model->index(0, 8), fieldofstudy);
    model->setData(model->index(0, 9), id);
}

QAbstractItemModel* TeachersModel::CreateTeacherModel(QObject* parent)
{
    QStandardItemModel *model = new QStandardItemModel(0, 10, parent);

    model->setHeaderData(0, Qt::Horizontal, QObject::tr("No Induk"));
    model->setHeaderData(1, Qt::Horizontal, QObject::tr("Nama"));
    model->setHeaderData(2, Qt::Horizontal, QObject::tr("Telepon"));
    model->setHeaderData(3, Qt::Horizontal, QObject::tr("Tanggal Lahir"));
    model->setHeaderData(4, Qt::Horizontal, QObject::tr("Jenis Kelamin"));
    model->setHeaderData(5, Qt::Horizontal, QObject::tr("Ijazah"));
    model->setHeaderData(6, Qt::Horizontal, QObject::tr("Jabatan"));
    model->setHeaderData(7, Qt::Horizontal, QObject::tr("Mengajar"));
    model->setHeaderData(8, Qt::Horizontal, QObject::tr("Bidang Studi"));
    model->setHeaderData(9, Qt::Horizontal, QObject::tr("Id"));

    #ifdef Q_OS_WIN
        client::initialize();
    #endif // Q_OS_WIN

    c.connect("localhost");
    unique_ptr<DBClientCursor> cursor = c.query("sia.teachers", BSONObj());
    while (cursor->more()) {
        BSONObj p = cursor->next();
        AddTeacher(model, p.getStringField("induk_no"),
                   p.getStringField("name"),
                   p.getStringField("phone"),
                   DateOfBirth(p.getField("datebirth")),
                   p.getStringField("sex"),
                   p.getStringField("certificate"),
                   p.getStringField("position"),
                   p.getStringField("teach"),
                   p.getStringField("fieldofstudy"),
                   QString::fromStdString(p["_id"].OID().toString()));
        }
    return model;
}

void TeachersModel::SaveTeacher(const QString &induk_no,
                                const QString &name,
                                const QString &phone,
                                const QDate &datebirth,
                                const QString &sex,
                                const QString &certificate,
                                const QString &position,
                                const QString &teach,
                                const QString &fieldofstudy)
{
    #ifdef Q_OS_WIN
        client::initialize();
    #endif // Q_OS_WIN

    c.connect("localhost");
    BSONObjBuilder b;
    b.append("induk_no", induk_no.toStdString());
    b.append("name", name.toStdString());
    b.append("phone", phone.toStdString());
    b.appendDate("datebirth", QDateTime(datebirth).toMSecsSinceEpoch());
    b.append("sex", sex.toStdString());
    b.append("certificate", certificate.toStdString());
    b.append("position", position.toStdString());
    b.append("teach", teach.toStdString());
    b.append("fieldofstudy", fieldofstudy.toStdString());
    BSONObj p = b.obj();
    c.insert("sia.teachers", p);

    // refresh proxymodel after add data to database
}

TeachersModel::~TeachersModel() {}
```

And this is the code for the call teachersmodel.cpp:
**teachers.cpp**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include "mainwindow/teacherspage/teachers.h"
#include "mainwindow/teacherspage/crud_teacher.h"

using namespace std;

Teachers::Teachers(QWidget* parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    proxyModel_ = new QSortFilterProxyModel;

    proxyView_ = new QTreeView;
    proxyView_->setRootIsDecorated(false);
    proxyView_->setAlternatingRowColors(true);
    proxyView_->setModel(proxyModel_);
    proxyView_->setSortingEnabled(true);
    proxyView_->sortByColumn(1, Qt::AscendingOrder);

    filterPatternLineEdit_ = new QLineEdit;
    filterPatternLabel_ = new QLabel("Cari data:");

    filterColumnComboBox_ = new QComboBox;
    filterColumnComboBox_->addItem("No Induk");
    filterColumnComboBox_->addItem("Nama");
    filterColumnComboBox_->setFixedWidth(200);

    addButton_ = new QPushButton("Tambah");
    addButton_->setFixedWidth(100);
    editButton_ = new QPushButton("Edit");
    editButton_->setFixedWidth(100);
    deleteButton_ = new QPushButton("Hapus");
    deleteButton_->setFixedWidth(100);

    connect(filterPatternLineEdit_, SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)),
            this, SLOT(filterRegExpChanged()));
    connect(filterColumnComboBox_, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)),
            this, SLOT(filterColumnChanged()));
    connect(addButton_, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(addTeacher()));

    QVBoxLayout *mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
    QHBoxLayout *filterLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
    QHBoxLayout *sourceLayout = new QHBoxLayout;

    filterLayout->addWidget(filterPatternLabel_, 1);
    filterLayout->addWidget(filterPatternLineEdit_, 2);
    filterLayout->addWidget(filterColumnComboBox_, 3);
    filterLayout->addWidget(addButton_, 4);
    filterLayout->addWidget(editButton_, 5);
    filterLayout->addWidget(deleteButton_, 6);
    sourceLayout->addWidget(proxyView_);

    mainLayout->addLayout(filterLayout);
    mainLayout->addLayout(sourceLayout);
    setLayout(mainLayout);

    teachersModel = new TeachersModel;
    try {
        SetSourceModel(teachersModel->CreateTeacherModel(this));
    } catch (exception& e) {
        qDebug() << "Caught " << e.what();
        QMessageBox::critical(this, "Error", e.what());
    }
}

void Teachers::filterRegExpChanged()
{
    QRegExp regExp(filterPatternLineEdit_->text(), Qt::CaseInsensitive, QRegExp::RegExp);
    proxyModel_->setFilterRegExp(regExp);
}

void Teachers::filterColumnChanged()
{
    proxyModel_->setFilterKeyColumn(filterColumnComboBox_->currentIndex());
}

void Teachers::addTeacher()
{
    CrudTeacher *crudTeacher = new CrudTeacher(this);
    crudTeacher->show();
}

void Teachers::SetSourceModel(QAbstractItemModel* model)
{
    proxyModel_->setSourceModel(model);
    proxyView_->setColumnHidden(9, true);
}


Teachers::~Teachers() {}
```

Comment: Why don't you just call `TeachersModel::AddTeacher` from `TeachersModel::SaveTeacher`?

Comment: Does the view update correctly if you remove proxy model and display main model directly?

Comment: Generally speaking, databases have no way of notifying clients that some data has changed, and IIRC Qt does not implement such notifications on the databases where they exist. Thus, what you're trying to do is generally impossible if the changes are done outside of your application. It might be possible for some specific database, and you'll still need to add your own code to that effect.

Comment: Okay thanks for all answer. So to update the view I must close and open again the widget.